# Load Testing with Asset Loading

Tags: testing, load, load-testing, stress-testing

I'm currently trying to load test a homepage I develop. Till now Loader.io was good enough for my purposes, but I realized it does not download/use the embedded assets.

Is there a load test service, which get's as close as possible to real users?

I haven't found anything until now. Hopefully somebody of you guys knows a suitable service.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) does it for sure:

[image]

See [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)

Moreover it simulates browser cache via [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)

If you rather looking for a "service" there are several options of running a JMeter test in the cloud starting from shell scripts like [JMeter ec2 Script](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) and ending up with end-to-end solutions like [Flood.io](https://www.flood.io/) or [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/)